# If $f$ and $g$ are paths with $g$ constant, then $f'\simeq g'$ rel$\{1\}$ if an only if there exist a free homotopy $f'\simeq g'.$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Using Theorem 1.6 (http://www.ugr.es/~acegarra/Rotman.pdf page 17), show (using the notation of exercise 3.2 (page 40)) that if $f$ and $g$ are paths with $g$ constant, then $f'\simeq g'$ rel$\{1\}$ if an only if there exist a free homotopy $f'\simeq g'.$

Attempt to the proof

$\implies$ direction

Follows immediately.

$\Longleftarrow$ direction

Suppose we have an homotopy $H:I\times I\to X$ such that $$H(t,0)=f'(t)$$ $$H(t,1)=g'(t)$$

We only need to find $H$ such that $H(1,t)=f'(1)=g'(1).$

Applying exercise 3.2 i) to $f$ and $g$, I have $f'\simeq g'.$ Since $g'$ is now constant, then $f'$ is nullhomotopic.

`Now I am not sure if I can use iii) from Theorem 1.6 because I have $f':S^1\to X$ and I need $f':S^n\to X$.` I am wrong in the previous line, in fact I can use the Theorem 1.6 with $n=1.$

I think now I can conclude that there exist an homotopy $H:f'\simeq g'$ such that $H(cte,t)=f'(cte),$ for all $t\in I.$

That is $H(1,t)=f'(1)$ for all $t\in I$.

I can have  $H(1,t)=f'(1)=g'(1)$ only if $H(t=1,1).$ How can I correct this?

Am I on the right track?

If someone could help me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confuse $f,g : I \to X$ which are closed paths and $f',g' : S^1 \to X$. Thus your homotopy $H : I \times I \to X$ cannot  be a homotopy from $f'$ to $g'$. So take a (free) homotopy $H : S^1 \times I \to X$ such that $H(z,0) = f'(z), H(z,1) = g'(z) = x_0$.

In Example 1.7 Rotman shows that if $f : S^n \to X$ is map and $F : S^n \times I \to X$ a homotopy such that $F(z,0) = f(z), F(z,1) = \xi$ for all $x$, then $f$ has a continuous extension $F' : D^{n+1} \to X$.

So let $H': D^2 \to X$ be a continuous extension of $f'$. Define
$$R : S^1 \times I \to D^2, R(z,t) = t \cdot 1 + (1-t)\cdot z$$
where we regard $D^2$ as a subset of the complex plane. The map $R$ is continuous. Define
$$H'' = H' \circ R : S^1 \times I \to X .$$
Then $H''(z,0) = H'(z) = f'(z)$, $H''(z,1) = H'(1) = f'(1) = x_0 = g'(z)$  and $H''(1,t) = H'(1) = x_0$. Thus $H''$ is the desired basepoint-preserving homotopy.

Comment: Did you mean $H''(z,0) = H'(z) = H(z,0) = f'(z)$ ?

Comment: Could you explain $H''(z,1) = H'(1) = H(1) = f'(1) = x_0 = g'(z)$ the second, third and fourth equality?

Comment: I corrected my answer (I made an error by referring to $H$ which does not play a role here). Since $1$ is an element of $S^1$ and $H'$ extends $f'$, we get $H'(1) = f'(1)$. That $f'(1) = x_0$ is from the *definition* of $f'$.

Comment: Thank you. Why $f'(1)=x_0$ is from the definition of $f'$? Is not $g'(1)=x_0$?

Comment: The general construction is this: You start with maps $f, g : I \to X$ such that $f(0) = f(1) = x_0 = g(0) = g(1)$. This gives you maps $f', g' : S^1 \to X$ such that $f'(1) = g'(1) = x_0$. In exercise 3.3 we only consider the special case that $g'$ is constant. By the way, $f' \simeq g'$ rel. $\{1\}$ *only makes sense* if $f'(1) = g'(1)$.

Comment: How is that $t \cdot 1 + (1-t)\cdot z$ lies in $D^2\subset\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Because $D^2$ is convex. To see this, let $a, b \in D^2,$ i.e. $\lVert a \rVert, \lVert b \rVert \le 1$. Then $\lVert t \cdot a + (1-t)\cdot b \rVert \le \lVert t \cdot a \rVert +\lVert (1-t)\cdot b \rVert = t \lVert a \rVert +(1-t) \lVert b \rVert \le t + (1-t) = 1$.